Why does a thread started inside PyGame GUI event loop slow down the GUI?
Some time ago I posted a problem about starting a thread inside a GUI loop, in which commands should run in parallel to the GUI event/drawing loop. This was supposed to be a measurement loop, which should be started and stopped according to the Users decision. I got an answer from stackoverflow and I have implemented the code into my app. It seems to work but it slows down the drawing and response of GUI elements (of course it shouldn't as it runs in separate thread). It lags so much, that the GUI becomes practicaly unresponsive. Although the measurement loop in a separate thread runs at normal pace. Should I run the redraw of a GUI in another thread? The shortened code is posted below. Some elements can be missing, although I tried to input everything that is essential to get an idea about how the app works.

#function to execute in separate thread - if measuring puts a random number in a queue 

def takeMeasurements(run, measure, q, sleep_time):
    while run.is_set():
        if measure.is_set():
            print("Measuring...")
            q.put(random())
        else:
            print("Not measuring...")
        sleep(sleep_time)

########pygame code######## 

pygame.init()

#here goes a lot of repetitive GUI code    
#{....}

run=True

MEASURE=False

#event and GUI update loop

while run:
    time_delta = clock.tick(60)/1000.0
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False  
        if event.type== pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
            if event.ui_element == button_set_param: 
            #if user pushes button starting measurement
                if stdb_run=="Standby":
                    pass
                elif stdb_run=="Run":
                    if MEASURE==False:
                        #initializing threading, only when MEASURE==False, so it executes only once
                        (threadRun := Event()).set()
                        (threadMeasure := Event()).set()
                        queue = Queue()
                        #start thread with sleep=1 s
                        (t := Thread(target=takeMeasurements, args=[threadRun, threadMeasure, queue, 1])).start()
                    else:
                        #if measurement run second time or more
                        threadMeasure.set()
                    MEASURE=True

        if event.type == pygame_gui.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
              #if User pushes stop button and stops the measurement
              if event.ui_element == button_stop:
                    threadMeasure.clear()

    try:
        #if the measuremnt was started, and  queue object exists, if not -> pass
        m=queue.get()
        #displaying a random number in GUI element
        entry_vbridge.set_text(str(m))
    except:
        pass

    #updating GUI
    manager.update(time_delta)
    manager.draw_ui(screen)
    screen.blit(surf, (750,400))
    pygame.display.flip()

#code on closing the app
try:
    threadRun.clear()
    t.join()
except NameError:
    threadRun=None
    t=None

pygame.quit()


I foolishly thought that maybe sleep() command in takeMeasurements function acts not only in the thread but somehow in the GUI update loop. There is thread.sleep(), but I can't use it in the functions body because the thread is not passed to the function as the argument.

It looks like your game loop blocks at: m=queue.get(). Did you mean: m=queue.get_nowait()?

Yes, Thanks @quamrana , i think i should change the code to:
try:
queue.get_nowait()
except:
pass

The main problem here is that there is no "real" multi-threading in Python -- at least not if you are using a regular Python implementation, that is, CPython. This means that at any moment only one Python-level thread can be running, since any running thread needs to have acquired the GIL (the infamous Global Interpreter Lock). In other words, Python-level threads are very different from C-level threads and only make sense for IO-bound tasks. If you have a non-IO bound, computationally heavy task, like "taking measurements", then it will block other tasks - unless your first task automatically and very regularly releases the GIL, giving control back to the Python main thread so that other tasks can run.
One way to avoid interference would be to implement the "taking measurements" code either in Cython or as Python extension module and making sure that it will release the GIL (either most of the time when it's running or very regularly). (Note that in pure Python code there is of course no way to release the GIL. You have to use either Cython or C code to do so. Implicitly, under the covers, some Python functions may release the GIL, but you cannot control this from pure Python code.)
If you cannot do that - for whatever reason - then another alternative might be to use multiprocessing instead of threading. So, let the "take measurements" code run in it's own process. This adds some extra overhead, but it should at least not interfere in a major way with the pygame code.
Python core devs have started working on a GIL-free implementation of Python, but that's currently only in the most early stages. I expect it will be at least a year or two (or more) before it will be ready.
Btw - Note that for game dev there is also a separate StackOverflow:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com. So, you might also want to search there for more info/answers/
